# Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException : unable to verify the first certificate Using Playwright C# While connecting Moon

Tags: c#, ui-automation, playwright, playwright-dotnet

Trying with below code connecting Moon. Can someone  please help me on this?  `Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException: unable to verify the first certificate Using Playwright`

Strack Trace:

```
onnection.SendMessageToServerAsync[T](String guid, String method, Object args)
    BrowserType.ConnectAsync(String wsEndpoint, BrowserTypeConnectOptions options)
    MoonDotNetCore.InitiateMoonWebDriver() line 68
    GenericAdapter`1.BlockUntilCompleted()
    NoMessagePumpStrategy.WaitForCompletion(AwaitAdapter awaitable)
    AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke)
    SetUpTearDownItem.RunSetUpOrTearDownMethod(TestExecutionContext context, MethodInfo method)
    SetUpTearDownItem.RunSetUp(TestExecutionContext context)
    <.ctor>b__0(TestExecutionContext context)
    <>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Execute>b__0()
    BeforeAndAfterTestCommand.RunTestMethodInThreadAbortSafeZone(TestExecutionContext context, Action action)
```

Code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> moonOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
moonOptions.Add("Http","--ignore-certificate-errors");
BrowserTypeConnectOptions launchOptions = new BrowserTypeConnectOptions() {
    Headers = moonOptions
};
var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
await playwright.Chromium.ConnectAsync("wss://moon.url.com/wd/hub", launchOptions);
```

Comment: What is moon? I can't find any reference to it.

Comment: Moon is a browser automation solution compatible with Selenium, Cypress, Playwright and Puppeteer using Kubernetes or Openshift to launch browsers. 
  https://aerokube.com/moon/latest/

Comment: i have similar probleme on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75003608/c-sharp-dotnet-why-websocket-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate  any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

If we set this parameter **IgnoreHTTPSErrors** , then the server will ignore doing the SSL validation. [Search here](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-browsertype)

You can set this in code and it will avoid the check

```
 public override BrowserNewContextOptions ContextOptions()
 {  
            BrowserNewContextOptions()
            {
                IgnoreHTTPSErrors = true
            };
 }
```

Once this is yet, the error related to "**unable to verify the first certificate**" will not come.

for API

```
    APIRequestNewContextOptions aPIRequestNewContextOptions = new(
                new()
                  {
                    IgnoreHTTPSErrors = true
                  }
             );
```

Here is the [documentation](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-apirequest#api-request-new-context) from playwright

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue recently.

1. The error you are getting means that the certificates presented by the moon server to your client is incomplete. Try to provide the full chain of certs there!
2. If later, you get the "WebSocket error: self signed certificate in certificate chain" then you need to set the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS env variable pointing at your pem file. This is happening being Node cannot read the trusted CAs by default.

This is the [question/solution](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/14204) I posted for the Playwright team along with the resolution.

Comment: i have similar probleme on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75003608/c-sharp-dotnet-why-websocket-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate  any help please ?